# How can I turn on the backup bios on my Z390 Aorus Pro Wifi?

Tags: boot, bios, backup

A couple months ago I was tinkering with my bios to enable secure boot, when I rebooted after updating the key platform, my monitor wouldn't show anything, my computer would still turn on but there was nothing displaying on the monitor. I tried resetting the cmos chip to try and get the bios back but it was the same error. I changed monitors but to no avail, I also tried shorting the cmos pin, nothing worked.

I read that I could turn on the backup bios, I have no idea how. I already had 2 tech geeks take a look at my computer but they have no clue how to fix it.

There is nothing on the manual about turning on the backup bios, I thought it would turn on automatically but that's not the case.

Comment: Might this work? https://www.pcinq.com/how-to-update-gigabyte-backup-bios/#:~:text=From%20power%20off%2C%20holding%20the,using%20the%20backup%20ROM%20exclusively.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the monitor is still not displaying something, thank you though.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer support if your model has backup BIOS and if so how to enable it. If working it is probably automatic.  My laptop has automatic BIOS backup.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Gigabyte's automatic backup BIOS doesn't work when you need it to, and works when you don't want it to. What I mean by that is that if you were to...say...overclock your memory too far, the board might just revert to a backup BIOS that's not even compatible with your CPU. That's the biggest reason why I wrote the backup BIOS updating guide that the other person linked.

I've spent years trying to get "stuck" Gigabyte firmware to "realize" that it's actually stuck and revert to backup, to no avail. Some boards have selector switches to force backup BIOS, but without that...the best you can hope for is to drain the battery for a couple weeks. Yes, I said weeks.

You see, the setting that gets "stuck" is a one that Gigabyte doesn't think should have anything to do with whether your not system hangs at that point.